# 'Cannot read property 'XX' of undefined' - API response object in state destructured

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a response from an API like below that I save to state using useState:

```
// API response
data: {
  propertyOne: 'some text'
  more: {
    propertyTwo: 'some text'
  }
}

// add API response to state
const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
setInfo(response.data)
```

When I destructor the object to output the text to the screen, `propertyOne` outputs fine, but `propertyTwo` gets an error `Cannot read property propertyTwo of undefined` on page load.

```
const { propertyOne, more: { propertyTwo } } = info

return (
  <View>
    <Text>{propertyOne}</Text> <!-- this outputs without error -->
    <Text>{propertyTwo}</Text> <!-- this gives undefined error -->
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Hey @cafPad this is because of the initial state. It is just an empty array initially that's why it breaks.

Comment: @YashJoshi What do I need to change this to?

Comment: Try this `more && more.propertyTwo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
<Text>{more.propertyTwo}</Text> <!-- this gives undefined error -->
```

Comment: Hey Rajan, this wont help because initially `info` is just an empty array.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that @YashJoshi